# In Spring Boot, how do you set a (extended) property using extended setters and getters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I am using Spring Boot, and have the following Entity definitions (abridged):

```java
package com.vw.asa.entities;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public abstract class CmsModel extends Model {
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private short isActive;
    
    
    public short getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }
    
    public void setIsActive(short isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
    
    public void setIsActive(String isActive) {
        if (isActive.equals("true")) {
            this.isActive = IS_TRUE;
        } else if (isActive.equals("1")) {
            this.isActive = IS_TRUE;
        } else {
            this.isActive = IS_FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have several models which extend this 'base' model, following this flavor:

```java
package com.vw.asa.entities.cms;

import com.vw.asa.entities.CmsModel;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Barry Chapman
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "cms_extra_questions", schema = "asa")
public class CmsExtraQuestions extends CmsModel {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    ...
}
```

When I initialize an instance of `CmsExtraQuestions` as a result of a hibernate query, if I call `setActive(true)` on the object, it has no effect on the members of that object. When I copy the setters and getters from the `CmsModel` base class into the `CmsExtraQuestions` class, it works fine.

```
$entity = new CmsExtraQuestions();
$entity->setActive(true);
```

Why does this not set the member properties of the instantiated object when calling the extended setter? If this is normal - is there a way to add these properties and member functions to the base model so that they can be inherited also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake, I forgot to add `@MappedSuperClass` to the inherited model, `CmsModel`. That allows JPA to map the properties from that class as though they were defined in the model that was inheriting that base class.

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class CmsModel extends Model {
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_active")
```